# Is doing $('#someId').click(function() on document.ready into thin air expensive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, document-ready

I have a website with some 25-30 different pages (pagetypes / templates, really, you probably get the idea).

For each of these, I hook up stuff on `$(document).ready(function() ...);` and I simply wonder if all of these functions can be put in the same .js file which implies that many of them will execute in vain since I hook on average 1-2 anchor clicks per page = 50 actions getting hooked up though only about 2 are valid for any given page.

I hope you follow. Just for clarity, here's some sample code.

In one and the same file, I have a lot of these though with different id's or classes being hooked up

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#options-toggler').click(function() {     
        $('#options').toggle(200);
        return false;
    });
});

....
```

The main point here is that I have some 50 or so functions like the above, being setup in one and the same file that is loaded on every page you visit but on any given page, there's only 1-2 elements that gets hooked up.

Is this bad practice? If so, what's the alternative? I can't imagine having ONE .js file per template but please do let me know what the best practice is for this.

Let me know in the comments if you need more info.

**EDIT**
Maybe it's unclear from the above text but the site is implemented in Python, NOT javascript. With Javascript I do simple stuff like updating counters, sending saves to the server etc. I see nothing but overhead in employing a Javascript framework, as has been suggested in at least two answers to this question.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about it. Javascript is slow anyway ;)

Comment: Levi's right, javascript is slow anyway and / though the speed penalty for this probably isn't that bad. However a nicer way would be to create external JS files that are loaded and executed after (document).ready and then re-think your strategy for selectors (or CSS classes, or the naming of your IDs) in such a way that things that have similar behaviors can be hooked by the same piece of code. In other words treat your DOM elements more as objects or classes.

Comment: Javascript is not slow - javascript is *insanely* fast.  The DOM is slow.  Try writing some javascript in NodeJS where it can run without a DOM.  You'll see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modularize partially like, say for example as followed

`main.js`

```
function initializePageOne(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#options-toggler').click(function() {     
            $('#options').toggle(200);
            return false;
        });
    });
    //Other initialization stuffs relevant to page one
}

function initializePageTwo(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#options-toggler2').click(function() {     
            $('#options').toggle(200);
            return false;
        });
    });
    //Other initialization stuffs relevant to page two
}
```

Then in `page1.html` put,

```
//reference to main.js
<script type="text/javascript">
    initializePageOne();
</script>
```

for `page2.html`

```
//reference to main.js
<script type="text/javascript">
    initializePageTwo();
</script>
```

This way the codes are all in `main.js`, but initialization is page specific

hope this helps

Comment: However, this will still download ALL the functions - 90% of which won't be used at all.  Good middle-ground from a dev / organising perspective tho.

Comment: @AlexMcMillan i know what you mean. But OP mentioned "I can't imagine having ONE .js file per template", so thought of a balancing one ;)

Comment: @AlexMcMillan use require js,  you do the same above this but load only those you want and NOT ALL functions

Comment: @Wishy Of course.. but his example shows no mention of `requirejs` and suggests dumping all functions into a single `main.js` file, included on all pages.

Comment: true! i was just trying to provide a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Update:
If you dont like frameworks such as angular or ember, try to use require-js which will help you to load what you want in a modular fashion so you could load only those hooks that you want to!

Is this bad practice? 
If you dont use a framework or modular script loaded(require) you dont have much of a choice

If so, what's the alternative? 
Use framework or a modular script loaded!

You should probably try to use ember.js or angular.js, basically any of the frameworks. Are you already using them? 

 Having 25-30 different pages using plain javascript without using any framework would be an extremely horrible experience.

P.S. => i had done an entire online shopping site using plain javsacript without any frameworks and it was horrible and so much of repeated code and difficulty in debugging, enhancing and everything! Once i learned ember i felt so relieved!

Comment: Your answer seem more like a comment to me. Frameworks are good for some, not so for others. I like being in control so no thanks on the frameworks.

Comment: your point that "i like being in control so no thanks on the frameworks" looks like you have misunderstood a framework. You could do whatever you want in a framework but in a more proven and optimal way

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to move to a structured framework like [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) or [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) you could just put each pages individual "hookups" into a `<script>` tag in the HTML.

This is usually sufficient for small sites, but once you get bigger you definitely want to implement some kind of framework.

Comment: Having them spread out in 25 files is what I want to avoid, hence my question above.

Comment: Okay, so you have 25 .html files, correct?  Each with its own "requirements" for "hookups"?  Small version: encapsulate the hookups into the .html files.  Better version: implement a framework.

Comment: Sincerely, I want to thank you for taking the time to answer, but I must really ask what is this fascination with frameworks? I'm implementing a regular site in Python with the need for some nice "live"-counters and savings without page-reloads. Adding a framework - learning it and getting it to work and the extra files to load etc etc - I just don't see the point with it. Feel free to prove me wrong. I write this with the best of intentions. Thanks.

Comment: Understood - sometimes it can be hard to not sound... annoyed lol but we're all friends here.  Frameworks are *relatively* simple to implement - usually just including a `.js` file in a `<script>` tag on your pages.  They make it *FAR* easier to manage larger projects, tho.  They do come with a certain onboarding cost / learning curve for your first project, but after that you will quickly realise the benefits.